# HTTP Post String with Same Parent Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I have created an http post request using rails and HTTParty, which is as follows...

```
xml = "<Member><Telephone-group><Value><PhoneNumber></PhoneNumber></Value></Telephone-group></Member>"
DeleteNumber.post("http://url/path/members/" + msid + "?securityKey=securitykey", :query => {:newValues => xml})
```

The aim is to remove the existing mobile(cell) phone number from the database by posting a blank string, which works fine. However, in the XML document that I am posting to, there are often multiple types of phone number, including home and work numbers. Unfortunately, they are all named the same, as follows...

```
<Telephone-group type="associated" writable="true">
  <Value>
    <PhoneNumber>01234567891</PhoneNumber>
    <PhoneType>H</PhoneType>
    <PhoneTypeDesc writable="false">Home</PhoneTypeDesc>
  </Value>
  <Value>
    <PhoneNumber>07123456789</PhoneNumber>
    <PhoneType>M</PhoneType>
    <PhoneTypeDesc writable="false">Mobile</PhoneTypeDesc>
  </Value>
</Telephone-group>
```

How can I specify that it only remove the mobile phone number? I know how this would be done using xpath, probably something like "**(//phonenumber)[..//phonetype = "M"]**", but I do not know how I can specify this using an http post parameter. Any help is much appreciated, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest that you download the entire xml, or at least the entire phone group portion, manipulate it within Rails, then post it back less the information you don't want in there...

Comment: This has to be iterated over tens of thousands of members and I'd like  to keep it efficient, with as little processing as possible

Comment: Then I would argue that you are therefore using the wrong tool for the job. To my knowledge HTTParty is for issuing simple get/post requests (per: http://www.rubyinside.com/httparty-web-api-rest-service-consumption-from-ruby-class-981.html)

Therefore HTTParty is for sending or receiving "stuff" that your Rails app has done. So if you have some logic you need ran on the fly, be it simple or complex then HTTParty probably isn't the tool for the job.

The correct usage of HTTParty would be to: pull down (via HTTParty) the XML, manipulate it, then push it back using HTTParty.